# Adding text to an existing textbox in a word document VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

My company creates a welcome packet for each new employee.  In this packet, it's our job to list their name, job title, etc.  We use a template for this; just a page within the word document that has textboxes for each field.

Is it possible to add info to those existing textboxes?  If not, how can I re-create the page in the document with new textboxes? It's the 3rd page.

I don't know if this is even possible, but if it is please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your textbox is called `Textbox1`. To add text to it simply write:

`TextBox1.text = Textbox1.text & "String here"`

Alternatively, if you want to wipe it out completely, go for

`Textbox1.text = "String here"`

Hope this helps!